# Minimize sum of products of partition

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, np-hard, partitions

I have a set of positive integer numbers $A = \{a_1,...,a_N\}$ and I need to find a partition of $A$ into two sets, such that the sum of their products is minimal, i.e.,
$$
 \min_{X,Y : X \cup Y = A} \prod_{x \in X} x + \prod_{y \in Y} y.
$$
Is there any good approximation/heuristic algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: This sounds a lot like the usual PARTITION problem. For example, the minimum $2\sqrt{\prod_{x \in A} x}$ is reachable iff $\log A = \{ \log a_1, \ldots, \log a_N \}$ can be partitioned into two equal halves.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152673/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4480170/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.